# camel-mail with attachment not working in Apache Karaf

Tags: java, apache-camel, jakarta-mail, apache-karaf

I am currently trying to integrate camel-mail feature in Apache Karaf.

Environment:
Java: `Open JDK 1.8.0_242`
OS: `Ubuntu 18.04`
Camel: `2.20.3`
Karaf: `4.2.0`

I have a simple route that polls imap endpoint to fetch emails. This email is dedicated to receive emails with attachments.

My route looks like:

```
from("imaps://{{IMAP_SERVER_URL}}"
                + "?username={{IMAP_EMAIL_USER}}"
                + "&password={{IMAP_EMAIL_PASS}}"
                + "&unseen=true"
                + "&delete=false"
                + "&initialDelay=100"
                + "&delay={{IMAP_POLL_DURATION}}")
                .routeId("pollIMAPServerRoute")

                // process the email and extract attachments
                .process(new EmailProcessor())

                // save a copy of the original content
                .to("file:{{ORDERS_STORE_LOCATION}}")
                .to("log:info");
```

The custom processor is inspired from https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mail-component.html#_consuming_mails_with_attachment_sample

The custom email processor is a simple one and looks like:

```
Map<String, DataHandler> attachments = exchange.getIn().getAttachments();

System.out.println(attachments.size());

if (attachments.size() > 0) {
    for (String name : attachments.keySet()) {
        DataHandler dh = attachments.get(name);
        // get the file name
        String filename = dh.getName();

        log.info(filename);

        // check if the attachment is an xml file
        // if not move to another attachment
        if(!filename.endsWith(".xml")) {
            continue;
        }

        log.info("email has an xml attachment");

        // get the content and convert it to byte[]
        byte[] data = exchange
                .getContext()
                .getTypeConverter()
                .convertTo(byte[].class, dh.getInputStream());

        exchange.getIn().setBody(data);
        break;
    }
}
```

This implementation works perfectly fine when executed from an IDE (in my case Netbeans). However, it fails to fetch any attachments if I execute the generated bundle in Karaf.

For ease and clarity, I have created a github repo where this issue can be replicated.

https://github.com/cooshal/karaf-camel-mail

assembly/ contains a custom karaf assembly
components/imap-consumer contains the route bundle

https://github.com/cooshal/karaf-camel-mail/blob/master/components/imap-consumer/src/main/java/com/krigosoft/eai/imap/consumer/routing/PollIMAPEmailEndpoint.java -> Route

https://github.com/cooshal/karaf-camel-mail/blob/master/components/imap-consumer/src/main/java/com/krigosoft/eai/imap/consumer/routing/EmailProcessor.java -> Processor

It would be great, if anyone could point me to something that I might have missed during the setup.

Comment: I do not see how can I relate your answer to my problem. could you please explain?

Comment: Was typing on my phone and pushed comment to wrong question. Sorry my bad.